# Email expiration tokens without usage of database and crontab deletion

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt

I have API server with Auth (registration, login, forgotten password, etc..) based on JWT token session.

When user forgot password, he gets email with unique token and link where he can reset his password.

At this moment, I am generating UUID token which is saved into database with expiration field.

After user reset his password or token expires, this token is invalidated. Invalidated tokens are deleted every midnight by crontab to keep database clean.

Is there any other way to do this? Maybe without usage of database?

I was thinking about bundling token UUID into JWT string. This way I do not need database row.
But then I realized, that this token will be valid until it expires, so user can change his password infinitely. Only fix I see is add this token into revoked list (in database) until it expires, but then I again used database :D

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Auth is a complex domain, I would use an existing solution like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) to handle this, as there are too many flows to consider.

That said, you can send a JWT token in the reset password link. It will have the expiry date and user id. Signed JWT tokens cannot be manipulated by users, so we can trust them on when they expire. This way you do not need a DB entry at all to track this.

Comment: Those solutions like Auth0 are not applicable in our app. About second paragraph: Yes, but when user use this token to reset password it needs to be invalidated, what is not possible in JWT. I can just add this token to blacklist (into database).

Comment: Usually these tokens expire shortly, like in 10mins to 3 hours. Worst case the user can reset his password multiple times during that timeframe. If it's important to use it only once, keep an audit of user actions (useful for other purposes also). If last 'user reset password' action is more recent that a token creation date, consider it as invalid.

Comment: Yes this is also way. Almost same as this solution: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/11/safe-password-resets-with-json-web-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

I found answer in [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/11/safe-password-resets-with-json-web-tokens/):

Create JWT token which is encrypted by secret made from current user's `password hash + time of last password change`. This way, token is one-time-use, because after user changes the password, next time someone tries to use this token again, token will not get decrypted correctly (not encrypted by same secret). In addition, if new password is same as old, token will still not be usable, because of additional timestamp information.

Another solution offered by @Horatiu Jeflea is to also use user's `time of last password change` to our advantage. Just ignore password change requests if token was generated before last change. In this solution is (I personally think) small chance that two password changes take place at same time what can mess this up, so I will use the first solution.

Comment: @Joe I disagree. JWT have expiration time built in. So token will expire after time you set... If user do not want to change password anymore, he just click "invalidate request now" and `last time changed timestamp` will get updated in database. This way, token is still unexpired JWT, but cannot be used anymore